# Build Rest API Request in XML

Tags: xml, rest

I want build rest api request with xml.
Can I do it, without use code else?

I would love to see an example.

I know that I can call service like that:

```
<Query>
<Method Name="Get...">
<Parametars>
<id>1</id>
<name>'Hila'</name>
</Parametars>
</Method>
</Query>
```

Thanks

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. stackoverflow is all about programming issues.

Comment: I'm looking for how to write it, because I couldn't find it anywhere

Comment: You can check SOAPUI: https://www.soapui.org/